# Excel 2013 - cannot enter numbers

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

I open a blank sheet. TYPE numbers into cells. Excel does not recognize the numbers as number. Even if I select and FORMAT as number. What is wrong. existing sheets work fine.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hi, can you provide a screenshot to better illustrate your problem?

Comment: No use. Things look normal. Then when I try to sum numbers in a column or use any formula the sheet acts like the numbers are text. A screenshot will show the SUM symbol does not light up to indicate the formula is valid. I will send aSS to try to illustrate.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the format is not enough if cells has been "Text"-mode (Numbers are aligned left per default).

You need to "update" the cells.

1. Enter a `1` (number) in a scratch / spare cell.
2. Place the cursor on that cell
3. Hold `CTRL` and hit `C`, so that you are able to paste that `1`
4. Select the cells you need to change; set them to "Number" format
5. Select "Paste special" from the Edit menu (older Excel) or ribbon
   *(Shift+CTRL+V in Libreoffice, possibly also in Excel)*
6. In the dialog that opens; select "Multiply" (i.e. by that selected `1`)
7. Click OK on the Dialog.

*From memory, I might have forgotten a step... Beware.

It will work as described in LibreOffice 6*